# Inserting structure into page Lotus

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have a little question. I developed a database using Lotus Domino Designer and I create a structure (MainStructure), then I create page (RootPage). Now I need to insert MainStructure into RootPage and I don't know how to do this. Can you help me?

Comment: What element type is (MainStructure)? Is it a outline?

Comment: To clarify: there is nothing called a "Structure" in the English language version of Lotus Notes and Domino Designer. We're trying to figure out what you mean. Perhaps you could show us a screen-shot.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you've done is create an outline, you will need to create a page, and within the page insert the outline with Create/Insert Embedded Element/Outline